# Sending array using sockets

Tags: c++, arrays, networking, winsock2

I have been trying to communicate with a WiFi wireless device. This device receives `9 bytes`.

By using Wireshark/CommView for WiFi, I discovered that the wireless helicopter takes `9 bytes.` For example `AA 64 00 00 00 00 00 00-BB`. I know what each byte represents so that's not the problem now.

The problem is that I am having problem sending the last two bytes together which is `00-BB` because it contains  `-` and it is different from others. Below is the code that I have now.

*NOTE: This code worked with the helicopter about 5 times but refused to work again. It connects and sends the array but the helicopter does not respond anymore and I believe that the last.*

```
//dont know how to represent the last byte which is 00-BB
char myText [9]= {0xaa, 0x64, 0x78, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8, 0x08,0x00, 0xbb};
while(1)
{
    //send message(bytes array)
    if (send(ConnectSocket, myText,sizeof(myText), 0)<0)
    {
        wprintf(L"Failed to send message!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        howmany++;
        cout<<"Message Number "<<howmany<<" SENT with "<< sizeof(myText)<<" BYTES  "<<endl;
    }
    Sleep(50);
}
```

Comment: The dash is just wireshark formatting, not part of the 9 bytes. Your helicopter probably has some other issue.

Comment: No, the doesn't have any problem. Actually, I saw the dash from commView not wireshack. Wireshack shows no dash in the signal. The iOS app that comes with it still work. It flies with the iOS app.

Comment: Believe @jbleners.  The dash is just output formatting.

Comment: @Peter, ok so how do I send the 00-BB? Does 00-BB mean 00BB? I dont understand that. Others such as 0xaa can easily be sent but the 00-BB is confusing. any ideas?

Comment: Which part of 'the dash is just output formatting' don't you understand? 00-BB means 00 followed by BB. The - means nothing.

Comment: In your head, replace the dash with a space

Comment: Thanks Peter and jbleners.

Comment: Thanks Peter and jbleners. The problem actually wasn't the array. It was where I put the array. I declared char myText [9] outside the while loop and also without initializing it and then initialized it inside the while loop and it now function properly. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: That didn't solve your problem, whatever it was. The code you posted here should work identically to that, and it is superior on efficiency grounds.